# Excel Conditional Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following spreadsheet:

...

I need a conditional formatting formula that colors the dates in the grid red if the are on the same day, same time, and are of the same event type (in column A as white text). I've tried a bunch of different `countifs`. The current formula is `=AND(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$20,$A5,I$5:I$20,$I5)>1,I5<>"")`. It doesn't discriminate by type, or day really, like I want. Any ideas?

Comment: What values are you placing in the grid? If it is a formula, what is the formula?

Comment: The grid is populate with the following formula ```=IF(AND($E5="Daily",I$3>=$D5,I$3<=$G5),$F5,IF(AND($E5="Weekly",I$3>=$D5,I$3<=$G5, TEXT(I$3,"DDD")=TEXT($D5,"DDD")),$F5,IF(AND($E5="Monthly",I$3>=$D5,I$3<=$G5, TEXT(I$3,"MM/DD/YYYY")=CONCATENATE(TEXT(I$3,"MM"),"/",TEXT($D5,"DD"),"/",TEXT($D5,"YYYY"))),$F5,"")))```

Comment: Row 3 is also populated with a formula but winds up basically the date in mm/dd/yyyy format, displayed as day of the month. Row 4 is also a formula that winds up displaying the first letter of the day of the week.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide clarification. Do not do that in comments. Nobody wants to read through a wall of comments to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one $ sign too many in your formula. Change the $I5 to I5.

Before

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$20,$A5,I$5:I$20,$I5)>1,I5<>"")
```

After

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$20,$A5,I$5:I$20,I5)>1,I5<>"")
```

[image]

Be aware, though, that with that formula alone, you won't be able to figure out WHICH event type has duplicates, especially if the duplicates are from different event types, like this:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! Nice catch. I would have stared at that forever and not caught the extra ```$```.

Comment: Yes, my next step is to come up with another conditional format rule for the event name list to catch the conflicts and highlight those rows too.